Is it possible to ask a question without signing in?
The body of this question is a test to see if we can ask a question without signing in

As an Unregistered user you were able to ask your test question on the Main site, and also to have it migrated successfully to this Meta site.
Nevertheless, I would encourage you to register your account to obtain the additional benefits outlined at Why should I create an account?
